# GtkAppChooser Content type for all applications and/or audio mixers

Tags: gtk, mime-types, gtk3, mixer

I'd like to have a GtkAppChooserButton which allows the user to select a program to run which will most likely want to be an audio mixer such as pavucontrol. Despite vague documentation on the matter I gather the app chooser's content type is meant to be a MIME type, however I cannot find a suitable MIME type for an audio mixer, or more generally just "all applications".

Some types such as `application/` will give two `Other Application...` options if `Other...` items are enabled, both of which are identical and neither of which contain half the applications I have, including any audio mixers. Aside from that, nothing else I do gets me remotely close to what I'm after.

Is there a MIME type and/or GtkAppChooser content type (they seem to be the same thing?) for audio mixers or just all programs in general? (I.e. Any program that would have an icon in the likes of the Gnome app launcher/xfce4-whisker-menu/etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I've come up with a solution, thought it may not be as clean as you hoped.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297473/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-programmes-with-python) mentioned a way to get the `GtkAppChooser` to "show all", but it doesn't actually show all applications you have installed. However from that I was able to work out how the `GtkAppChooser` is using `Gio.AppInfo`, which has `Gio.AppInfo.get_all()` (this is for PyObject) which returns a full list of Gio.AppInfos for all applications I have installed, provided they have a .desktop file.

So, my "solution" is to write my own app chooser which gets a list of apps from `Gio.AppInfo.get_all()`.

I've cleaned up my previous solution to this and written a class 'AllAppChooser' to inherrit `Gtk.Dialog`, giving much greater customisation. The completed dialog looks like so:

[image]

And the code used:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio


class AllAppChooser(Gtk.Dialog):
    """Provide a dialog to select an app from all those installed.

    The regular Gtk.AppChooserDialog does not seem to provide any way to allow
    selection from all installed apps, so this dialog serves as a replacement.

    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(self)

        self.set_default_size(350, 400)
        self.set_icon_name('gtk-search')
        self.set_title('App Chooser')
        if parent:
            self.set_parent(parent)

        self.content_box = self.get_content_area()
        self.content_box.set_margin_left(8)
        self.content_box.set_margin_right(8)
        self.content_box.set_margin_top(8)
        self.content_box.set_margin_bottom(8)
        self.content_box.set_spacing(8)

        self.button_box = self.get_action_area()
        self.button_box.set_margin_left(4)
        self.button_box.set_margin_right(4)
        self.button_box.set_margin_top(4)
        self.button_box.set_margin_bottom(4)

        self.label = Gtk.Label('Choose An Application')
        self.content_box.pack_start(self.label, False, False, 0)

        self.list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, int)

        pixbuf_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        text_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        icon_column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('icon', pixbuf_renderer, icon_name=1)
        text_column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('text', text_renderer, text=0)

        self.tree_view = Gtk.TreeView()
        self.tree_view.set_model(self.list_store)
        self.tree_view.set_headers_visible(False)
        self.tree_view.append_column(icon_column)
        self.tree_view.append_column(text_column)

        self.view_port = Gtk.Viewport()
        self.view_port.add(self.tree_view)

        self.scroll_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scroll_window.add(self.view_port)
        self.content_box.pack_start(self.scroll_window, True, True, 0)

        self.ok_button = self.add_button(Gtk.STOCK_OK, 1)
        self.ok_button.connect('clicked', self.on_ok)

        self.cancel_button = self.add_button(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, 0)

        self.selected_app = None
        self.app_list = []

    def populate_app_list(self):
        """Populate the list of apps with all installed apps.

        Icons are provided by icon-name, however some apps may return a full
        path to a custom icon rather than a themed-icon name, or even no name
        at all. In these cases the generic 'gtk-missing-icon' icon is used.

        """
        self.app_list = Gio.AppInfo.get_all()
        for i in range(len(self.app_list)):
            gio_icon = self.app_list[i].get_icon()
            app_icon = 'gtk-missing-icon'
            if gio_icon:
                app_icon = gio_icon.to_string()
            app_name = self.app_list[i].get_display_name()
            self.list_store.append([app_name, app_icon, i])

        self.list_store.set_sort_column_id(0, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)

    def run(self):
        """Run the dialog to get a selected app."""
        self.populate_app_list()
        self.show_all()
        super().run()
        self.destroy()
        return self.selected_app

    def set_label(self, text):
        """Set the label text, \"Choose An App\" by default."""
        self.label.set_text(text)

    def on_ok(self, button):
        """Get Gio.AppInfo of selected app when user presses OK."""
        selection = self.tree_view.get_selection()
        tree_model, tree_iter = selection.get_selected()
        app_index = tree_model.get_value(tree_iter, 2)
        self.selected_app = self.app_list[app_index]
```

This is then run similar to a regular dialog:

```
app_chooser = AllAppChooser()
application = app_chooser.run()
```

If the user exits the dialog box or presses cancel then the result will be None, but if they selected an application then `run()` will return a `Gio.AppInfo` object for the application which you can then do with as you please. For example, to launch your newly selected application:

```
application.launch()
```

I feel this is now a relatively solid solution, but I still welcome additional suggestions. Additionally, if there is a way to do this in Gtk without having to do all this stuff I would still love to hear it.